# ImportError: cannot import name 'Run' from 'borb.pdf' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/borb/pdf/__init__.py)

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, pdf-generation, importerror, borb

```
from borb.pdf import Document
from borb.pdf import Page
from borb.pdf import Paragraph
from borb.pdf import Run

pdf_text = """
Long text here
divided in various sections
"""

# Create a PDF document
document = Document()

# Split resume text into sections
sections = pdf_text.split("\n\n")

# Iterate over sections and add them to the PDF document
for section in sections:
    paragraph = Paragraph()
    runs = [Run(text=section)]
    paragraph.add(*runs)
    page = Page()
    page.add(paragraph)
    document.add(page)

# Save the PDF document to a file
document.save("updated.pdf")
```

In the above code I'm trying to insert text into pdf using borb

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-d90b0d6013d2> in <cell line: 8>()
      6 from borb.pdf import Paragraph
      7 #from borb.pdf.text.run import Run
----> 8 from borb.pdf import Run
      9 #from borb.pdf.text.run import run
     10 

ImportError: cannot import name 'Run' from 'borb.pdf' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/borb/pdf/__init__.py)
```

But I'm getting the above error, is 'Run' function deprecated ?  and How to solve above error ?
Thanks.

Comment: did you go throu the borb library code?

Comment: I have a similar error with `from borb.pdf import PDF`. It says: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'borb.pdf'; 'borb' is not a package`. I'm curious if someone will shed some light on this.

Comment: @NicolaeOlariu Have you installed `borb` by running `pip install borb`? Because from the error, it seems like you haven't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**disclaimer:** I am the author of the `borb` library.

You are (most likely) trying to run some code that was generated by chatGPT (or similar). I know (from experience) that it will try to invent new classes that simply don't exist in `borb`.

Recently even, I did an experiment where I fed chatGPT the entire `README.md` of `borb` to see if it could answer a simple query. And it failed. And in one of these tests, it also used a non-existent class `Run`.

I would suggest you read the documentation. It's very comprehensive, and easy to follow along. You don't need an AI to write the code for you.